# Pandas and Tensorflow: want to save Pandas Dataframe to .npz file

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I know saving np array to save in .npz file format for the TensorFlow input file using the np.savez(np.array) method. But I have worked on file using Pandas. Now I want to save in .npz file format for the TensorFlow input file.

Please Help!

Comment: If there is no specific method, please suggest an alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Pandas DataFrame into a numpy array (df.values) and do the same

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
kwargs_dict = df.to_dict('list')
np.savez(path, **data_dict)
```

This gets the pandas DataFrame as a dictionary of `key(colum name):value(dataframe coulmn)` and gets then saved as various numpy arrays. Not sure that is what you needed. Hope it helps!